# Multiple and() conditions in where clause for couchbase lite Android client

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

In my Android app we use couchbase lite database version `2.8.6`

I run three database queries.

- One item in where clause.

```kotlin
QueryBuilder.select(
    SelectResult.property("id"),
    SelectResult.property("timestamp"),
    SelectResult.property("rating"))
.from(DataSource.database(database))
.where(Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string(DOC_TYPE)))
```

In the result I see three items from database printed to a console. As expected. Format here ans below is `id|timestamp|rating`

```
4e39f79c-9e11-4aba-9fb6-95d910f46cd9|0|-2147483648
e95646ee-ba3a-4978-b2a8-5383f31be2f1|0|-2147483648
e02d0eb3-6c9b-4942-b43c-a752eefc77a8|1630525956184|2147483647
```

- I add `and()` condition to `where()` to get all items where `type = 'type' AND rating < 1`

```kotlin
QueryBuilder.select(
    SelectResult.property("id"),
    SelectResult.property("timestamp"),
    SelectResult.property("rating"))
.from(DataSource.database(database))
.where(Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string(DOC_TYPE))
   .and(Expression.property("rating").lessThan(Expression.intValue(1))
)
```

Result is as expected as we search everything with `rating < 1`, third item is filtered out.

```
4e39f79c-9e11-4aba-9fb6-95d910f46cd9|0|-2147483648
e95646ee-ba3a-4978-b2a8-5383f31be2f1|0|-2147483648
```

- Finally, I want to see records where `type = 'type' AND rating < 1 AND timestamp <= 1`

```kotlin
QueryBuilder.select(
    SelectResult.property("id"),
    SelectResult.property("timestamp"),
    SelectResult.property("rating"))
.from(DataSource.database(database))
.where(Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string(DOC_TYPE))
   .and(Expression.property("rating").lessThan(Expression.intValue(1))
       .and(Expression.property("timestamp")).lessThanOrEqualTo (Expression.longValue(1))
                    )
            )
```

And now the result is really strange as I receive three items form the database. And the third one has `timestamp` much greater than `1` put into the query.

```
4e39f79c-9e11-4aba-9fb6-95d910f46cd9|0|-2147483648
e95646ee-ba3a-4978-b2a8-5383f31be2f1|0|-2147483648
e02d0eb3-6c9b-4942-b43c-a752eefc77a8|1630525956184|2147483647
```

Any ideas how to make it work with multiple `and()`? If I try to remove the second `and()` and keep the third one everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep investigations I found several problems in my code:

- `.and()` should be called at the end of the "child" condition and not at the "parent" level.

For the conditions like this

```kotlin
val condition1 = Expression.property("type").equalTo(Expression.string(DOC_TYPE))
val condition2 = Expression.property("rating").lessThan(Expression.intValue(1))
val condition3 = Expression.property("timestamp")).lessThanOrEqualTo (Expression.longValue(1))
```

The correct way is

```kotlin
.where(condition1.and(
            condition2.and(
                condition3.and(
                    ...
                )
            )
        )
```

but NOT like I've tried

```kotlin
.where(condition1.and(condition2)
                 .and(condition3)
                 .and(...)
      )
```

- For the creation of the object I used a code that converts an object to `Map<String, Any>` before saving to couchbase. Everything seemed to be OK till I realized that `Long` was converted to `Double`.
- The last point, I have much complicated queries and inside one of them I accidentally used `.add()` instead of `.and()`. No comments.

Hope this will help to somebody to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the query would be as you did originally:

.where(condition1.and(condition2)
.and(condition3)
.and(...))

I think there is an additional parenthesis here that seems to be wrong:

.and(Expression.property("timestamp"))